# Inverse of a function with exponent variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, inverse-function

Consider a function $f(x)$ such as $x\mapsto 2e^x-\frac1{e^x}$. How do you find $f^{-1}(x)$?

I have tried, logarithms, squaring, substitution, but I wasn't able to isolate $x$. The correct answer, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+f%28x%29%3D2e%5Ex-1%2Fe%5Ex) is $f^{-1}(x) = \log{\left(\frac14\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+8}\right)\right)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with

$$x=2e^y-e^{-y}$$

and multiply both sides by $e^y$, you get

$$x e^y=2e^{2y}-1$$

which you can treat as a quadratic equation in $e^y$. Use the quadratic formula to solve for $e^y$ (be careful in choosing roots!), undo the exponential with the logarithm, and you have your needed result.

Comment: Right, I actually tried that! But this solved to $y=0$ (choosing the right root, like you said), hence eliminating all $y$-terms. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, you can figure out why the minus sign in your original question is wrong...

Comment: BTW, what do you mean??

Comment: As another way of thinking about it: is $x$ always bigger than $\sqrt{x^2+8}$? Having thought about it, which of $+$ or $-$ should you choose in the quadratic equation?

Comment: Right, it should be $\pm$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Milosz, plugging in $x = 0$, you get $f(0) = 1$.  Therefore, $f^{-1}(1)$ should be $0$.

Comment: Nonono, $\pm$ means you have two signs to choose from. To know which one to choose, consider my previous comment.

Comment: @DJC: yes, that's another good sanity check, but I wanted Milosz to think about why he shouldn't be subtracting within the logarithm in this case...

Comment: Oh.  My apologies.  I can delete the comment if you like.

Comment: @DJC, indeed. In my first attempt to a solution I tried factorization, which gave me $(a-1)(a+\frac{1}{2})=0$ where $a=e^{y}$. Hence solving for $y$, gives $y=0$. This however, wouldn't allow me to isolate $y$. I didn't consider the quadratic formula which clearly was the way to go. @J.M. thanks, I see what you mean. The argument of the logarithm cannot be negative!

Comment: @DJC: No need, and no worries; it helps to have more than one way to see that your solution's hunky-dory. :)